# Sql Server sysjobsteps step_uid column nullability

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am working on a project creating a log table of sorts for failed jobs. Since the step_id can change depending on step order, I wanted to use the step_uid as a unique identifier for a step. With that in mind, is seems that the step_uid in msdb's sysjobsteps table is a nullable column, and I am relying on that column NOT being null as of yet.

Does anyone know why or when that column would ever be null. No examples exist on my current server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By looking at the source code of the `sp_add_jobstep_internal` stored procedure, we can realize that the `step_uid` will allways be filled-in by this procedure.

Moreover, the `sp_write_sysjobstep_log` stored procedure assumes that `step_uid` cannot be null (it copies its value into the `sysjobstepslogs` table, where `step_uid` is defined as NOT NULL).

I think the `step_uid` column was defined as nullable only because it did not exist in SQL Server 2000. However, since SQL Server 2005 it seems to be always filled-in.